# Concatenating strings with integers and floats?

Tags: python, concatenation

Sup guys and gals,
I'm in the very beginnings of learning to code with python and am building a very basic percentage calculator to get the gears turning mentally.

I am having an issue with running a successful flow-through with the program:

```
#Percentage Calculator

print('Enter value of percent: ') #prompt user for input of percent value
percent = input() #gain user input about percent *stored as 'str'
percent = int(percent) #store and convert user input into an 'int' from 'str' for use in line 11

print('Enter value of percentaged number: ') #prompt user for input of percentaged number value
percentagedNum = input() #gain user input on percentaged number *stored as 'str'
percentagedNum = int(percentagedNum) #store and convert value from 'str' into 'int'

answer = percent / percentagedNum #calculate percentage formula

print(percent + '% of ' + percentagedNum + ' is ' + answer) #prompt user with answer
```

Also, the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1438, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Custom/PycharmProjects/PercentageCalculator/main", line 12, in <module>
    print(percent + '% of ' + percentagedNum + ' is ' + answer)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I feel it's a concatenation issue with mixing strings, integers, and floats in the final print() function call.

Getting some good eyes on this would be greatly appreciated and thanks for all you guys do to help out the community. Much love.

Answer (score 1):

you need to first cast the numbers as strings.  you can do this explicitly:

```py
print(str(percent) + '% of ' + str(percentagedNum) + ' is ' + str(answer))
```

or you can let Python f-strings take care of it:

```py
print(f'{percent} % of {percentagedNum} is {answer}')
```

the reason what you were trying didn't work is that the `+` operator has different results depending on what was given to it.  If it has strings on either side, it concatenates:

```py
>>> "foo" + "bar"
"foobar"
```

if it has integers on either side, it adds them:

```py
>>> 5 + 3
8
```

When you mix the input types, it's not sure what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Ah, I see. After turning them into integer data types, I have to convert them back into string data types, after the formula calculation.

Lesson learned: Always keep data types the same, when concatenating.

Thank you again, David.

Answer (score 0):

In your `print` statement, make sure that you turn variables that contain numbers into strings by using `str()`: `str(percent)` and so on.

Indeed it's a classic error when you begin Python.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, Pac0. I see that I have to change the data type of the ```percent = int(percent)``` back into ```percent = str(percent)``` to concatenate properly in the final ```print()``` function without a runtime error. Much appreciated, sir.

Comment: @Glenn : and that applies for the other variables as well. Not that I am not fond of "changing the type of the variable" often like `variable = sometype(variable)`. It can lead to more confusion than necessary on the long run. You can simply just format them as string _when printing only_ like this : 
`print(str(percent) + '% of ' + str(percentagedNum) + ' is ' + str(answer))`. Of course, it can be a bit hard to read. David's answer is much more readable code! (that's important, we write code for _humans_ like yourself and your colleagues, more than we write code for computers!)

Comment: Yes. Applying data type changes to the other vairables, as well. F-strings sound more handy for the solution. However, it's always  welcome to learn concatenation limits. Truly appreciate, you guys.